# iptables redirection works only from outside

Tags: iptables

I created a Kubernetes cluster using VirtualBox on a dedicated server with a public IP (ex: 65.12.12.12).

This cluster has an internal network, based on subnet 192.168.205.0/24 and when I deploy a web app it assigns an IP for this subnet to it.  For example I deploy a helloworld Nginx it get assigned a private IP of 192.168.205.100.

Now, from the external world, I cannot `curl 192.168.205.100` as it's private, so I was trying a way to map the public IP (65.12.12.12) to this one.

So I did this.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 65.12.12.12 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.205.100:80
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 65.12.12.12 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.205.100:443
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o vboxnet1 -j MASQUERADE
```

This now works smoothly.

From outside I can `curl` the public IP and get the page as it gets redirected to the private IP.

But, when I'm inside the server, I cannot do the same, like the `iptables` it's not being used.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

… having expectations w/o studying how things work?

Locally originating traffic won't follow the same way as external does.
Instead of `PREROUTING` you'd need using `OUTPUT`.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about accessing external resources from inside, but only show us your working NAT.

Try `iptables -L -v --line-numbers` to print your entire chains' config and show us the other as well. :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lucax88x/fe2498b2813d95085402793dc6ad740b

Comment: have to check in detail, but are you sure, that you want policy accept on INPUT?

Looks like you're using ufw? So why are you mixing ufw and iptables?

I'd suggest to re-create everything from scratch using this tutorial: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-ufw-to-forward-port-80443-to-internal-server-hosted-on-lan/